# Datat frame won't print in new order using arrange() function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Not sure why my new data frame will not print in the new order despite the codes working. Any idea why?

```
  CR <- data2[data2$cv == "CR",]
    colu <- CR[,c(5:7,9:36)]
    vector <- c("L8", "L12", "H12", "H16")
    
    for (i in colnames(colu)){
      ANOVA <- aov(reformulate(c('block', 'loc'), i), data=CR)
      ANOVA_SUMMARY <- summary(ANOVA)
      test1 <- HSD.test(ANOVA , "loc")
      df <- as.data.frame(test1$groups)
      df %>%
        rownames_to_column(var = "Treatment") %>%
        mutate(Treatment = factor (Treatment, levels = vector)) %>%
        arrange(Treatment)
      print(ANOVA_SUMMARY)
      print(df)
      write.table(df, file = "CR_output.txt", append=TRUE)
    }
```

Comment: You are not having the results of your pipe back to the df variable. The pipe commands return a new object. You must save it somewhere if you want to use it again.

Comment: Oh I see it now! thank you!! I essentially erased df next to the first pipe and piped everything to the df assignment.